# How do you calculate the path by removing the current file name from the full path, in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io

How do you calculate the path by removing the current file name from the full path? I have this so far:

```
fullPath = mfilename('fullpath')
curMfile = mfilename();
path =
```

But I don't know what to put for path.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(filename)`